# In VB 2013, is there a way to differentiate between a keyboard entry and a scanner entry?

Tags: vb.net, keypress

In Visual Basic 2013, is there a way to differentiate between a keyboard entry and a scanner entry?

We have a program that the user will scan numbers into our system. On rare occasion, when the scanner does not work properly, the user will have to manually type the number in. As far as I can tell, VB sees the scanner entry the same way it sees the keyboard entry. Is there some piece of code that can check for a difference? Here is what I have started:

```
Private Sub CARD_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)   Handles CARD.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
            If Me.CARD.Text <> "" Then
               CardValidation()
            End If
        ElseIf e.KeyChar <> "" Then ' if entry a KEYPRESS then 
            DisplayErrorCodes()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you mean some scanner hardware that connects to the keyboard port or some other serial/custom port?  The most common method of these scanners is to emulate the key sequence required for the numbers, so no, the software won't be able to easily tell where the 'keystrokes' came from.

Comment: `does not work properly` means it reads wrong entry or just blank?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very easy to do but you CAN differentiate input from different devices.

The is an excellent article on CodeProject which covers this exact topic, here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any clean solution to suggest as the scanners usually send the keys the same way a regular keyboard would.

However, you may try to calculate the number of milliseconds between each KeyPress events.  Indeed, the scanner will usually send the KeyPress faster than a human would normally type on a keyboard.

Of course, this solution has it's limitations:

- It won't work if the scanner return a single KeyPress event.
- The millisecond threshold between human typing and scanner input is very suggestive.
- It requires handling between each KeyPress events and the context will be determined only after a sequence of KeyPress events.
- You'll need to define a number of milliseconds to wait after the last KeyPress event to flag the scanner input as completed (also very suggestive).

Before going with this solution, I would definitively try Sam Makin's solution which seems way more robust.